# How does Airplay from iCloud actually work?

Tags: network, icloud, appletv, airplay

Airplay from iCloud is part of the newest Apple TV update however I don't understand how it is supposed to work. Should I see a new option on my device when I'm airplaying something from it? This is all I could find on apple.com

`Apple TV will play content from iTunes in the Cloud instead of your AirPlay device when possible. Requires iOS 7 on AirPlay device.`

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4448?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. If the video exists on the iTunes store and you have AirPlay from iCloud enabled on your Apple TV via the settings app then once you start playing a video from your iOS device and send it to your Apple TV via Airplay you will see a rectangle with the video description on the top half of the tv like you are playing a video directly off the Apple TV. You can tell for sure it is playing via iCloud by hitting the home button. If the video continues to play then it is playing via 'AirPlay From iCloud'. Otherwise the video would stop playing.

Answer (score 1):

Found this unofficial item:

> Today’s update also brought AirPlay From iCloud, which lets guests
>   stream their purchased music, photos, and videos stored in iCloud to
>   another person’s Apple TV. If you bought World War Z on iTunes, you
>   can now go to a friend’s house with an Apple TV and watch it there
>   without having to log into their Home Sharing account or store it on
>   your phone. It’s all streamed from iCloud.

So, I guess you browse the iTunes store (or maybe the Videos app) on your phone, select something you bought, tell it to start playing, and then AirPlay it over to your friend's ATV.  Or your own ATV, I guess, although it would seem easier to play it on your own ATV using the ATV menu itself.

Comment: How is that different from before?

Comment: Because you start playing it from the iTunes Store, not from a local copy on your phone.  Even in the Videos app, you can (sometimes) view all of the TV Shows you've bought, even those not on your phone (this was inconsistent for me in iOS 6, haven't checked in iOS 7).  So, you can now start playing from the Store/Cloud, without a local copy on your phone, and the Airplay it to the ATV.  The ATV will get the video directly from the Store/Cloud, so you can (theoretically) shut your phone off and it will keep going.  Haven't tried this myself, but post back if this works for you!

Comment: Finally got around to trying this, instead of just reading/guessing.  OK, just ignore my "answer".  I can't get this to work myself, even trying from the Videos app and the iTunes Store app.  Neither one would let me start a video on the ATV2 that's NOT on my iPhone.  Not at first.  I had to go to Settings -> iTunes Store, and enable "Show all video".  Then, from the Videos app, select an episode NOT on the phone and it starts playing on ATV (having previously turned on Airplay).  Buffering can take a while (5-10 minutes for an episode of Archer), but it works.

Comment: Putting phone in Airplane mode stops AirPlay though, so PART of the data is going through the phone.  Hopefully not the entire video (twice, once on the way down from the Store/iCloud and once again on the way to the ATV), but the phone is still required for the video to finish playing.

Comment: I found that if you receive or make a phone call the video will be paused as well.